# How can I play as The Impostor more effectively in Among Us?

Tags: among-us

I love playing as The Impostor, however I am not good at it. Most of the time one of the following happens:

- I self-report a body and lose because it's obvious who was with the body
- I run away from the body and someone reports it and lose because I'm running away from it
- I am caught venting and voted out

Sometimes, I am lucky and get away with it, but it's pretty unique that it will happen. Is it me, or are these strategies bad? If they are bad, what's a good straightforward useful strategy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most of your problems are related to people discovering the body. Social tactics are another core part of playing impostor but that’s so broad I can’t address it here.

The easiest step you could take to reduce the frequency the  corpses you make are discovered is to use your tools of sabotage. As an impostor you have a variety of abilities that allow you to disrupt the game and restructure the priorities of the crewmates.

The simplest and one of the most effective tactics is to wait until you are alone with a crewmate, sabotage a crisis on the opposite side of the ship, and immediately kill the solo crewmate. The crisis will draw other crewmates to fix it, which brings them away from the body, allowing you to slip away and have plausible deniability. The best part? If the crewmates ignore the crisis and let the timer reach zero then. you win!

The second critical sabotage you can create is to kill the lights. This reduces the crewmate’s vision to about what is an arm’s reach away, anything outside of that length is obscured. While the lights are off you, as an impostor, retain full perception and can seek out and kill with a high level of impunity. Even in a crowded room you can still kill unseen if the lights are out.

The last sabotage you can inflict is locking doors to a hallway. This is still a powerful tool if used properly. The core use of locking a door is to briefly keep people out of a room, or to purposefully lock people in a room. Locking others out of a room allows you to kill and vent away while guaranteeing there are no witnesses. Likewise, trapping somebody in a room may give you enough time to finish your kill cool down and strike again before your quarry is able to escape. Both forms of door sabotage are situational, but in the right situations they can be used to great effect.

There are an endless supply of tips to maximize your killing potential when playing as impostor - but the best teacher is practice. As you play more rounds of Among Us you’ll learn through trial and error what tactics work best and what tactics get you caught. It’s not fun to be caught now but as you play more sessions your skill level will increase and you will become more lethal.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

**You kill Yellow at navigation.**

The most smart thing to do is to sabotage the reactor, and vent to the most nearby. Be careful, though, there are lazy crewmates who do not fix sabotages.

If you self-report, give fake proof as much as you can:

**Red wasn't fixing reactor. He was headed towards Shields. The body was in navigation. He is sus.**

If you have an imposter teammate and/or the crewmates figure out that you lied, **SPECIFICALLY SABOTAGE LIGHTS.** When a crewmate fixes lights and one is camping on the button, have your teammate or you kill them and lock Electrical doors. That will give you extra time for your cooldown and your sabotage. Sabotage Lower Engine and Storage, then sabotage Cafeteria on timing.

If you are caught venting, you can easily kill the crewmate that watches you. If it is multiple crewmates, sabotage the cafeteria, or where they are headed to and that will give you extra time for your imposter teammate to double kill them, leaving the last one to call a meeting and you and your teammate can give proof to vote them out. If you do not have a imposter teammate for this, sabotage where they are headed and call the meeting, saying that one vented, and say that the other crewmates are probably the other imposter(s) for vouching.

These are the strategies I rarely use to play, because they are on-the-top players in-game.

**EDIT:** If you get away with your kill by luck, sabotage the body environment or sabotage lights so the vision to the body is low, sabotaging electrical when the crewmates are done fixing lights. You need to fake lights, so they don't sus you. Come from the opposite direction of the body.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful *where* you kill people.  The more foot traffic a place gets, the quicker a Crewmate will find the body — or worse, catch you in the act.  When possible, stick to rooms that only have one entrance.

Comment: This does not work all the time. Sometimes if you can kill in a busy room, it can cause crewmates to start arguing and then both of them will be more sus than you. Also, killing in Electrical mostly seems to backfire for me even though it is heavily sealed off